# Login to Python web app from Lazarus FPC desktop client

Tags: python, authentication, flask, lazarus, flask-user

I have successfully deployed my Python web app in Pythonanywhere, complete with login authentication using flask-user.

I want to programmatically login to this Python web app from a Lazarus FPC desktop client so I can interact with the API. Of course I have knowledge of valid username/password combos. I see no obvious way to do it, and from security standpoint not straightforward as it seems. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I gleaned from Googling, and from other forum the following:

- A web app is meant to operate with some human intervention. My app
  was like that, so authenticating outside of the web app is a lot more
  work (at my level), but doable.
- A REST API is meant to drop payload to another app (or human) and authentication is handled differently.
  I need to rework my app to be more like this.
- If you develop in
  FPC/Lazarus, you also have the option to develop a REST API or server
  and deploy them in a paid VPS or your own box, thus removing the need
  for a Python app.